# Where is Inno Setup uninstaller executable?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm very new to Inno Setup, so forgive my ignorance on this one.

I created a very small install script and it's building and working the way I want—I get my setup.exe built to the output directory, and all the source files are being copied to my specified destinations.

Now I want to make sure users can uninstall the files that I specified in my `[Files]` section of my script.  The problem is I don't understand how Inno Setup handles this.  I assume Inno Setup *doesn't* make an executable specifically for Uninstall, but even if I run setup.exe after I have installed my application, the wizard doesn't ask if I want to uninstall.

However, if I enable the `Run` menu's `Target Uninstall` in the ISC compiler, I am able to uninstall the files.  So my question is, how do I uninstall my application outside of the ISC compiler.  In my `[Setup]` section I do have `Uninstallable=yes`.

I know this is a total noob question, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: whoops, just realized I can uninstall via the Add/Remove programs feature from control panel.  Hopefully this won't get downvoted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(As you have found yourself),* Inno Setup creates an entry in *Add/Remove Programs* Control Panel applet (if [`CreateUninstallRegKey`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_createuninstallregkey) is `yes`).

The entry is a link to an uninstaller program, which is generated by the compiler (when [`Uninstallable`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallable) is `yes`).

The uninstaller program is located by default in the application directory (unless overridden by [`UninstallFilesDir`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallfilesdir)) and is named `unins001.exe` (the number is incremented, if needed, to avoid naming conflicts).